# How do I model a crumbling egg yoke?

Tags: modeling, texturing

Does anyone have an idea how I can create a realistic looking hard boiled egg yoke, it has this rough and crumbling texture and if I were to model it by hand it would take forever and propably wouldn't look random enough. I can't find any egg yoke texture on the internet and don't know much about creating one on my own. Maybe on of you can help me with this, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using using a texture made for clay and editing the colour to orange. I also tried some things out with the normal map, you could propably do a better job if you just create your own normal map and put an orange image texture on it.